:active отваливается при перетаскивании


div {
  width:600px;
  height:100px;
  background: green;
}

div:active {
  background: red;
}
<div></div>



Необходимо присвоить стили блоку в момент когда происходит касание и удержание. Ок, на тачскринах это работает.
Но, не опуская касание, необходимо сместить, переместить палец на экране, не отпуская. В момент когда происходит смещение, :active отваливается. И необходимые свойства на момент когда касание все еще активно, уже не задействованы для блока
:hover не выход, поскольку после касания, hover по прежнему активен...
Есть ли выход, за счет css?

быть может так... <style>#xyz:focus{...}</style><div id='xyz' tabindex='1111'>...., еще можно глянуть в сторону атрибута draggable как и в целом механизма drag&drop, но это уже с js. а вообще, не помешает более... конкретное описание желаемого результата.

UPD: для тачей есть свойство touch-action с довольно интересным набором значений. может что то да пригодится.

:focus он тоже самое что и :hover, не отваливается когда касание перестает быть активным

Смотрела в сторону touch-action, но так толком не разобралась. Добавила пример в вопрос. Если на тачскрине нажать на блок и с зажатым касанием поводить по нему, :active отвалится.

И потом, зажатое косание может выходить за пределы самого блока...

Очень интересно, почему при мыши все работает как надо, просто отлично. А на тачскрине совсем никак не работает. По сути срабатывает в момент клика и все...

у тачей на зажатое движение как минимум и обработчик скрола может реагировать, у мыши же под это дело колёсико/трэкбол есть. может <div onscroll=''> сбросить :-/

Попробовала, не помогает(
